# What is the keyboard shortcut to type fast in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am not sure what is the best way to word my question correctly in single line. But basically I have seen quite a few video tutorials now where the coder types really fast using some sort of shortcut to fill in the automatic text(prolly intellisense stuff) It looks very similar to Linux command line tab where you only type half of your text and when  you hit tab it either fills in the gap or show you the remaining options.
Hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: I love the way you worded your title :-)

Comment: I call it 'code completion'

Comment: Definitely +1 for the title.

Comment: Baby is learning how to use a computer. Baby presses keyboard shortcut. Baby is now a 100WPM typist.

Comment: Press the Tab key to pick the selection in the auto-completion dropdown.

Comment: Does your computer have a Turbo button?  If so, press it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> completes the current variable/class you are typing.

Typing things like `ctor` and then pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice tells Visual Studio to insert a constructor for you. (Also works with `for` for a for loop, `cw` for a `Console.WriteLine();`, etc.)

For a full list, please refer to the [official reference from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx).

Comment: Fantastic. This is what I was looking for. I love this kind of shortcuts or ways to make my work more efficient.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess Ctrl+Space works. I was thinking the answer was Ctrl+V. Note that Code Snippets are only supported in a subset of languages, including C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I believe its `Ctrl-Space`, which is pretty common among most IDE's